# Tabular with Math symbols

Tags: math-mode

I try to compile the following code and my latex doc shows an error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ amssymb, amscd,mathrsfs,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[lastpage,user]{zref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{12}{10}{10}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}



{\rowcolors{3}{green!80!yellow!50}{green!70!yellow!40}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Πίνακας Ολοκληρωμάτων} \\
\hline
Aπλές Συναρτήσεις& Σύνθεση  \\
\hline
$\int\limits\ 0\mathrm{d}x=c$ & AF  \\
$\int\limits\ 1\mathrm{d}x=x$ & AX    \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\ln|x|$ &AL  \\
$\int\limits x^a \mathrm{d}x=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$    &DZ  \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x$ & AS  \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{x}$ & AD    \\
$\int\limits \sigma\upsilon\nu x\mathrm{d}x=\eta\mu x$ & AO  \\
$\int\limits \eta\mu x\mathrm{d}x=-\sigma\upsilon\nu x$ &AL  \\
$\int\limits\frac{1}{\sigma\upsilon\nu^2 x} \mathrm{d}x=\epsilon\varphi x$   &DZ \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{\eta\mu^2 x}\mathrm{d}x-\sigma\varphi x$ & AS \\
$\int\limits e^x\mathrm{d}x=e^x$ & AD   \\
$\int\limits a^x\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}$ & AO  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code. Surely, not all those packages are relevant to the problem you're experiencing. Part of your job is to isolate the problem by posting the shortest code that reproduces that problem.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Using in a trial latex doc the basic packages it runs fine. I want to embed the code for the tabular inside a main latex doc and it shows error. What is the problem?

Comment: What is the error? I had a package clash with the xcolor package which I just moved earlier in the preample and it worked just fine. However I removed the ```mnsymbol```package as I don't have it installed and it seems to be just a font.

Comment: @VagelisBebelis It should be `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`; on a case insensitive file system the calls are equivalent, but this one should be used in any case.

Comment: @egreg Yes it compiled fine now.

Comment: Of course `\DeclareMathSizes{10}{12}{10}{10}` is completely wrong, from a typographical point of view.

Comment: @Giannis That your code compiles or not in a given situation is irrelevant to the the need for isolating the problem, in order to save you and those willing to look into your problem some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package pdfpages loads package `eso-pic` which in turns loads package `xcolor` without any options. The solution is to move `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and fix capitalisation of `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` as mentioned by egreg.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ amssymb, amscd,mathrsfs,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[lastpage,user]{zref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{12}{10}{10}


\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}



{\rowcolors{3}{green!80!yellow!50}{green!70!yellow!40}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Πίνακας Ολοκληρωμάτων} \\
\hline
Aπλές Συναρτήσεις& Σύνθεση  \\
\hline
$\int\limits\ 0\mathrm{d}x=c$ & AF  \\
$\int\limits\ 1\mathrm{d}x=x$ & AX    \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\ln|x|$ &AL  \\
$\int\limits x^a \mathrm{d}x=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$    &DZ  \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x$ & AS  \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{x}$ & AD    \\
$\int\limits \sigma\upsilon\nu x\mathrm{d}x=\eta\mu x$ & AO  \\
$\int\limits \eta\mu x\mathrm{d}x=-\sigma\upsilon\nu x$ &AL  \\
$\int\limits\frac{1}{\sigma\upsilon\nu^2 x} \mathrm{d}x=\epsilon\varphi x$   &DZ \\
$\int\limits \frac{1}{\eta\mu^2 x}\mathrm{d}x-\sigma\varphi x$ & AS \\
$\int\limits e^x\mathrm{d}x=e^x$ & AD   \\
$\int\limits a^x\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}$ & AO  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}


\end{document}
```